# Pandas Pivot Table showing incorrect values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I am trying to transform my dataframe into a pivot table however I am getting incorrect values for some dies and correct values for other. Here is my code:

```
df['Period'] = df['Year'].astype(str) + '-' + df['Month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
df = pd.pivot_table(data=df,values='Ship_Qty',index='Die_Number', columns='Period',aggfunc='sum',fill_value=0)
df
```

[image: And here is the output of the code]

The values are WAY off as Die 540 sum  of 2020-01 is actually 33,105,450. Here is a picture of proof:

[image: 540 Sum]

Other places however have the correct sums. Die 12043 has the sum as 8250 and that is the correct sum in Excel:

[image: Die 12043]

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Here is also the columns of the data if this helps:
[image: Columns]

Edit:

Here is some of the data:
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMDwc.png)

I also changed the Ship_Qty to a float64 from a Object. While that decreased the numbers to something closer, it is still off by 10 million.

[Here is the new results. It also changed the periods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlUNd.png)

Here is the data types:

[Data Types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mnsGC.png)

Comment: first off, will be tricky for us to help without your actual data here. That said, is your table being read in correctly in the first place? That is, is 'Ship_Qty' being read in as a number that can be summed? Or is it sometimes a number but sometimes a str (object in pandas) because the commas are messing it up? Your very big 'sums' in your output don't look like numbers, the commas are every 5 or so, not every 3, so it doesn't look like it is adding numbers but rather concating strings

Comment: I added more information about the data. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: the period headers look like are changed because the values for year and month are now float (instead of being int or str before), and so '2020' is instead '2020.0'. So you just want those to be str (without the '.0' at the end), or int, or in your string methods remove the '.0's as for why the sums are still off, here's some troubleshooting advice for it: filter your starting dataframe (pre-pivot) to the same filters as you have in excel and look at them to confirm that they actually have all the sum numbers in them. with the filters do a `.sum()` on the column to see what it gives

Comment: I changed the values for year and month so they are now int. I filtered the dataframe using the following code  `newdf = df.loc[(df.Die_Number == 540) & (df.Month == 1) & (df.Year == 2020)] 
newdf ` And I got 1180 rows instead of the 2200 rows in excel so that means for some reason they are not getting picked up

Comment: if you just look at newdf, does it have the same values in Ship_Qty as when you do the filtering in excel? if you do `newdf['Ship_Qty'].sum()` do you get the same as the sum in excel?

Comment: the `newdf['Ship_Qty'].sum()` gives me a sum of 18106830. The excel sum value is 33105450.